# "How to clone a legendary permanent?" appears to be becoming an unbounded collection. What should we do?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

**[How to clone a Legendary permanent?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29751/how-to-clone-a-legendary-permanent)** appears to be becoming an unbounded collection question, with many answers mentioning only a single card that could do the trick. Sorting from oldest, we see the following undeleted answers, scores in brackets:

1. **[19]** Comprehensive answer, covering several cards and general mechanics
2. **[2]** [Helm of the Host](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Helm%20of%20the%20Host)
3. **[2]** [Rules Lawyer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rules%20Lawyer)
4. **[1]** [Spark Double](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spark%20Double)
5. **[0]** Comprehensive answer, covering several cards and general mechanics
6. **[-2]** [Sakashima of a Thousand Faces](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sakashima%20of%20a%20Thousand%20Faces)
7. **[0]** [Sakashima of a Thousand Faces](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sakashima%20of%20a%20Thousand%20Faces) (again)
8. **[1]** [Helm of the Host](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Helm%20of%20the%20Host) (again) (while mentioning a way to overcome the steep cost)
9. **[0]** [Double Major](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Double%20Major) (not mentioned in any prior answer)

[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) says this kind of situation is not good: every answer is equally valid, because every answer is mentioning a solution. That said, the more comprehensive solutions are arguably better answers.

Is this a problem? If so, what can/should we do about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question does not have the problems of list questions because it is not asking for a list, and there is nothing wrong with a single question having multiple valid answers. This question is asking for a tool or strategy for accomplishing a goal; an answer that provides a single complete strategy for accomplishing that is a valid answer. There can be many such answers and there is nothing wrong with many of those answers being posted.

As an analogy, consider a StackOverflow question about how to accomplish a programming task. An answer that suggests a tool to accomplish that task is a valid, complete answer. It is not invalidated by the existence of other tools that could be used to accomplish the same task, and it is perfectly valid for others to post other answers about using those other tools.